# Delete a record successful, but it delete all records in the database in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ms-access-2010

i have a problem. This is happen when i tried to delete a single record in the database when the program runs. The delete record is working, but it is delete all record in the database. How do i fix that? First of all, i view data in my database using datagridview, and once the user click certain row, and the user click delete, it is supposed to delete a certain row that user has been selected, but it is delete all records.

Here is the code:

```
private void DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fifthForm.comboBox1.Text == "English")
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM [SeranneRecord]";
            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                    dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index);
                    adapter.Update(ds);
                    dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = 
                             new System.Media.SoundPlayer(
                             @"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                    sound.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully", "Deleted");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks, also i want to ask about how to modify the records using datagridview. Thanks

Comment: your query is missing the where clause, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, my query is missing the where clause, but since using the datagridview, i don't know what to put in the parameters when i am using the where clause

Answer (score 2):

You are removing the data grid row : (`dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index);`) but you are not using any information from that row to create a WHERE clause in your query. You need something like `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE RecordName = 'RecordToDelete'.

Comment: But how do i let the computer know that the only the selected row that has been selected that's gonna be delete? if not using datagridview, i have to use PARAMETERS right? but i don't know how to do that when using datagridview. How should i do?

Comment: Does your row have a cell value that you can read? For example, if dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0] has your record name in, you can use that to construct the delete query.

Comment: could you give me an example how do i delete a record from datagridview?

Comment: It depends how you set up the DataGridView initially. Maybe  one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193385/delete-row-from-datagridview or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c01b3aaf-8f52-4b40-94f8-f35b65b8a932/delete-a-row-from-a-databound-datagridview-c will help?